# Odd upvoting pattern?

Tags: support, votes, etiquette

I haven't been very active on the site lately.  In the past several days I've noticed that very old crusty answers of mine have been getting upvoted what seems like an atypical amount.  Is anybody else experiencing atypical reputation increases? Is there a way for me to determine if the upvotes are legitimate?

Comment: It seems you have a fan :). It is indeed a little bit odd, because within a day all votes happened at the same minute (check the reputation tab). If it is a fan, it is someone who knows the system, because apparently the upvoting was limited to a maximum of 4 per day, which did not trigger the routine which roll 'row votes' back. It is very positive of you to report this odd pattern (now wait if something can be done), but I'd say if you are confident your posts are good, don't worry.

Comment: Nothing really jumps out at me. If as far as you know there is no fraud, you should have nothing to worry about. This sort of thing does happen on occasion.  Presumably, someone noticed & liked a post of yours, & so went looking through your profile for other posts they might like & upvoted a bunch. As @AndreSilva points out, the individual is presumably SE-savvy.

Comment: Peculiar indeed. I clicked through all 20 of your answers serially upvoted in the last days (https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/196/russellpierce?tab=reputation) and almost all of them (17 or 18) currently have exactly 1 upvote. This cannot be a coincidence. Moreover, the 2 or 3 answers that do not have 1 upvote, have exactly 10 upvotes. (CC @AndreSilva)

Comment: @amoeba That matches my less rigorous spot check... thats part of why I reached out - I didn't think that these were unrealized instances of me being insightful.  I thought some of them might be attempts to give an answer a score > 0 in the face of no answers or other 'meh' answers... but now that I look back maybe that wasn't happening as much as I thought (or someone looking through this decided to upvote other answers).

Comment: @amoeba, perhaps someone motivated to what gung said, also decided to improve our unanswered question ratio stat.

Comment: Just for the record happened to me a while back too. Same pattern. I assumed Father Christmas was getting in some early practice.