# Strange upsurge in up-voting of my questions

Tags: support, votes

I have noticed an unexpected upsurge in the frequency by which my past questions are being upvoted. Whereas for most years of my membership I had maybe on average one or two upvotes in a week, since about two weeks now, I have had multiple upvotes per day. My score has risen +294 in the past week (rank #40) and I am among the top 5% this week.

This may be a coincidence or related to more frequent usage of CV in general, but it still seems very odd to me. Has anybody made similar experiences?

A similar question has been discussed in this [thread](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5462/i-get-surges-of-upvotes-and-they-are-lumpy-in-time-is-this-because-the-site-is) and this [thread](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5111/odd-upvoting-pattern). Several answers are given:

1. Somebody found an Q/A they liked, clicked on profile and found more Q/A they liked; including giving you a boost because your Q/A's were under-appreciated.
2. It happens all the time. (not sure what this means?)
3. You have a fan.

I find these explanations still somewhat unsatisfactory. In particular, I have had around three upvotes per day. If explanation 1 or 3 would apply it is likely the upvotes would stop after some days. I really judge it unlikely anybody will come back to my profile over a period of weeks to vote on 2-4 questions per day. Explanation 2 seems to hint that this is a common problem of unknown origin. I somehow feel that there is more than this going on, but perhaps not.

Comment: @gung I have amended my question to make clearer what is not discussed under the other threads.

Comment: Re your edit: how is it a "problem"?

Comment: @amoeba Come on, isn't it strange that this is happening? Nobody complains about positive feedback, but it does not seem to reflect the trend/statistics of the past years. I think it is either some sort of stalker or a bot.

Comment: I'm going to speculate a little here, because I don't have direct evidence, but I do have some data to support it (which unfortunately I cannot reveal).  At least one of our long-time members exhibits a pattern of actively seeking out sets of related threads, edits them, often upvotes the posts in them, and sometimes answers them.  Except for the fact that the editing clutters the page of "active" threads, the behavior is unobjectionable and indeed praiseworthy.  I suspect around a third of your posts might have been accessed in this fashion.

Comment: I really wouldn't assume or even guess at malice here without explicit evidence. Minimal disclaimer: It is not me.

Comment: @whuber if my recent upvotes are indeed related to this practice, it would indeed be commendable.

Comment: @tomka, the thing is that there's basically no way to know--not for users, & not even for moderators. The result is that the answers given to the duplicates are the answers that can be given. Like amoeba, I don't see a problem here (& I see no reason to suggest a bot).